# VS Code: git incorrectly highlight changed lines

Tags: git, encoding, visual-studio-code

VS Code highlights some "changed" lines: 
[image: "changed" lines example]

But at the same time Activity Bar does not see any changes: 
[image]

Also `git status` output:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This issue occurred after changing the file encoding: 
All files in repository are encoded with `Windows-1251`. 
The attribute `working-tree-encoding` in `.gitattributes` is the same as `files.encoding` in `settings.json`.

Comment: A bit unclear question. However, the red line shows a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'Модуль, содержащий'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1251')` returns `РњРѕРґСѓР»СЊ, СЃРѕРґРµСЂР¶Р°С‰РёР№`

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening here is that you've told Git to use one encoding (windows-1251) for your files but your editor is using another one (probably UTF-8).  Setting the working tree encoding tells Git that it should store UTF-8 internally but that when checking out and adding files it should use a different one.

Note that if you've modified the value in `.gitattributes` but have not run `git add --renormalize .` and then done a commit, then this can also occur.  It's also possible that everything is set up correctly now, but someone previously checked in code that wasn't correct, and now you have differences.

Note that absent a compelling reason, you should use UTF-8 (without a byte-order mark) whenever possible.  The working tree encoding is there to help people who have to use legacy tools which are incapable of handling UTF-8, such as certain tools on Windows (which always want UTF-16).  If your tooling is capable of handling UTF-8 (and, in 2021, it definitely should be), then UTF-8 is your best bet.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem in the editor, because only he sees non-existent changes. I think I should create an issue in the VS Code repository.

I changed `.gitattrubutes` because the git web interface is not showing files correctly (due to encoding).

I completely understand what you are talking about UTF-8, but I am working with legacy Fortran code. And it's a problem that Russian characters are 2 bytes in UTF-8, so now I have to make concessions.